# how to merge 2 sql queries

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic

I have 2 queries I'd like to merge into 1 result (maybe 2).

What I have:

Table `records`:

```
 id | action
```

And I want result:

1. [optGroup](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_optgroup.asp) of 3 rows for last added rows
2. optGroup of 3 rows for most using action msg

So, I tried:

[image]

But when I tried to show up by server-side ASP page:

```
sql = "SELECT TOP 3 [action],COUNT([id]) as pocet "  & vbcrlf &_
    "FROM [IT].[dbo].[records] "  & vbcrlf &_
    "GROUP BY [action] ORDER BY pocet desc; "  & vbcrlf &_
"SELECT TOP 3 [action] "  & vbcrlf &_
    "FROM [IT].[dbo].[records] "  & vbcrlf &_
    "WHERE [email_numbers] <= 0  "  & vbcrlf &_
    "GROUP BY [inputdate] desc"
```

By using `Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")`

and just trying:

```
response.write "<optgroup label='3 most used'>"
while not rs.EOF
    response.write "<option value=''>" & rs("action") & "</option>"
    rs.movenext
wend    
response.write "</optgroup><optgroup label='3 last records'>"
while not rs.EOF
    response.write "<option value=''>" & rs("action") & "</option>"
    rs.movenext
wend
response.write "</optgroup>"
```

Show me this result:

```
SELECT TOP 3 [action],COUNT([id]) as c 
FROM [IT].[dbo].[records] 
GROUP BY [action] 
ORDER BY c desc; 

SELECT TOP 3 [action] 
FROM [IT].[dbo].[records] 
WHERE [email_numbers] <= 0 
GROUP BY [inputdate] desc

Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server error '80040e14'

Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'desc'.

/get.asp, line 1024
```

There is no problem with returning results by ADODB.RecordSet, there is problem with SQL query or using twice: `while not rs.EOF`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You query is wrong. You cannot use `DESC` keywork on `GROUP BY`, remove it and the query will work:

```
SELECT TOP 3 [action],COUNT([id]) as c 
FROM [IT].[dbo].[records] 
GROUP BY [action] 
ORDER BY c desc; 

SELECT TOP 3 [action] 
FROM [IT].[dbo].[records] 
WHERE [email_numbers] <= 0 
GROUP BY [inputdate]
```

Next, when you get to the EOF of the first recordset, you need to move on to the next one:

```
Set rs = rs.NextRecordset
```

So your code is:

```
response.write "<optgroup label='3 most used'>"
while not rs.EOF
    response.write "<option value=''>" & rs("action") & "</option>"
    rs.movenext
wend    
response.write "</optgroup><optgroup label='3 last records'>"

Set rs = rs.NextRecordset

while not rs.EOF
    response.write "<option value=''>" & rs("action") & "</option>"
    rs.movenext
wend
response.write "</optgroup>"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use union all between your queries

```
select * from  1
union [all]
select * from 2
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the SQL query

```
SELECT TOP 3 [action] 
FROM [IT].[dbo].[records] 
WHERE [email_numbers] <= 0 
GROUP BY [inputdate] desc
```

You can only use the `desc` keyword with `ORDER BY` and not with `GROUP BY`